# Scenebuilder-8.2.0. scenebuilder-launcher.sh missing

Tags: eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder, eclipse-mars, gluon

first of all I am using a Mac, Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 and gluon's Scene builder 8.2.0. When I set the path of the executable in my preferences->JavaFX, the launcher is looking for a scenebuilder-launcher.sh file which is not in my folder.

In my Contents/MacOS folder are only libpackager.dylib and SceneBuilder (exec).

I have to use version 8.2.0.

[image: This is the message I receive]

Comment: I solved it by downloading the latest Version of Oracle's SceneBuilder 2.0 and copying the scenebuilder-launcher.sh into my current folder.

Comment: I have the same settings, and it works fine for me. Make sure that under Preferences->JavaFX, the SceneBuilder executable shows `/Applications/SceneBuilder.app`